# Center three containers on one row padding between each

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to learn bootstrap but am having trouble with this part. If the page is being viewed on a laptop (or higher), I want three containers to be on the same row, centered on the page, and have some padding between each. If viewed on a mobile phone, I'd like the images to show in one column, one under the other. I can get the view to look nice when just creating it for a laptop or higher or I can get the collapsed view to look nice for a cell phone. Trouble is I cannot figure out how to get them to work together. I've tried using bootstrap column class .col-md-[some number] but it seems to not work with my css. Can someone please help? Below is a link of what I've created for a laptop view that I need to have look nice in cell phone or tablet also. [example view](http://tinypic.com/r/bjgz9f/5)

```
  /* need three of these centered on one row, with padding between them (if laptop or higher). */
  <div class="row center">
    <div class="showcase">
        <img alt="Text" src="image.png" height="100" />
        <div class="tabs">
            <h6>Text</h6>
        </div>
        <p>
            Some Text
        </p>
        <a href="#">Click Here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS for creating the three containers.
    .center {
       float: none;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
    }

```
.showcase {
   float: none;
 background: url("../images/home-boxes.png") no-repeat;
 height: 324px;
   width: 222px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   font-size: .9em;
   text-align: center;
}

.showcase h6 {
font-weight: bold;
}

.showcase p {
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: You need to assign your "showcase" div an additional class which would be whatever the bootstrap equivalent to a column is. Probably .col-md-4

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: If you mean this: class="showcase col-md-4". I just tried that to no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your hierarchy. Your row needs to be the parent of the 3 containers. Each of those containers needs the col-md-4 class.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you...now it works as it should. If you want put your comment in as an answer to my question, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change your hierarchy so that it looks something like this

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <!--contents-->
 </div> <!--/first column-->

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <!--contents-->
 </div> <!--/second column-->

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <!--contents-->
 </div> <!--/third column-->

</div><!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bootstrap, the breakpoints are designated by large, medium, small and extra small.  These relate to pixel values set in the variables.less file.  They can be anything you want.  They are not device dependent, so if you're going to use Bootstrap you should begin thinking about it in those terms.

Your problem description lacks some detail, so I'm not sure what you mean by "not looking nice." Looking at your code, right away I see that you are fighting against bootstrap by setting width and height styles.  One of the primary purposes of bootstrap is to let it control the width and height of objects on the screen for you.  If your divs are getting too wide or too narrow, you adjust things using the bootstrap framework. There are a couple of ways to do this.  First you can adjust the breakpoints of the page.  Next you can set the container class to a narrower max-width, say 960px.  That way things don't spread so much.  You can insert spacer divs that reposition elements in an inline row in the large view, but are hidden in any other view. Finally, you can use padding and margins to control the dimensions of the elements.  The trick is to work with Bootstrap, not against it.

If your problem is just a matter of margins and padding, you are going to need to use a media query that uses the same break values as bootstrap. That way the padding adjusts to the view, and everything looks nice.

You  can either use a media query in your own LESS file or in your CSS file.  It's better to use the LESS file because you can use the same variables that Bootstrap uses, but you don't have to if you're not comfortable with LESS.  The default breakpoints in Bootstrap 3 are:

```
// Small screen / tablet
@container-tablet:             ((720px + @grid-gutter-width));
@container-sm:                 @container-tablet;

// Medium screen / desktop
@container-desktop:            ((940px + @grid-gutter-width));
@container-md:                 @container-desktop;

// Large screen / wide desktop
@container-large-desktop:      ((1140px + @grid-gutter-width));
@container-lg:                 @container-large-desktop;
```

So if you are going to use these values in your CSS with your showcase class, your media queries would look something like this:

```
//default styles used and large view
.showcase {
background: url("../images/home-boxes.png") no-repeat;
padding-top: 10px;
font-size: .9em;
text-align: center;
}

//medium view styles
@media (min-width: 940px) and (max-width: 1139px) {
.showcase {
padding-top: ?px;
font-size: ?em;
}
}

//small view styles
@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 939px) {
.showcase {
padding-top: ?px;
font-size: ?em;
}
}

//extra-small view styles
@media  (max-width: 719px) {
.showcase {
padding-top: ?px;
font-size: ?em;
}
}
```

Use these styles in conjunction with the col-md-x, etc styles, and I would get rid on the float style.  Again, let bootstrap do the work for you.

Comment: thanks for the nice write up. I have seen the word LESS file, but at this early stage in my bootstrap infancy, do not know how to work with them. I did not know I needed to use any media queries. I will take your suggestions, try to understand them and see how I can use them to make my site more responsive. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Mike.  The key to working effectively with Bootstrap is understanding LESS.  But first you should familiarize yourself with media queries and how they function.  The media query is at the heart of responsive design in general and Bootstrap in particular.  Essentially, a media query lets you control and change styles based not only on the screen size, but also the output device being used.  This means that you can do things like use a completely different look when your page is printed, eliminating for example social media links and other objects that are important to screen interaction.

Comment: Hey Sean, thanks for commenting again. I have learned how to use media queries and am using them now (minimally at least) and am going to put my little knowledge to the test because I have a table of data that I want to reformat when viewed on a phone sized viewport. Thanks for checking back in.